# Sharepoint 2007 Search for published documents?

Tags: 2007, search

I have a lot of document libraries and many documents in different versions. While i'm searching a document it finds the last version of document (for example: v 1.4). But i want to see the published version on search results. For that example v 1.0. 
Thanks,

ilker

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is based on your permissions. If you are allowed to see version 1.4, then that is what you see. Otherwise, if you are only allowed to see the major versions in the library, you'll see version 1.0 (2.0, 3.0...).

Comment: That is correct, the search results are security trimmed based on the current user.